# Given P idempotent, show that I−P is idempotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, idempotents

So my task is well summed up by this older post:

[Given $P$ idempotent, show that $I-P$ is idempotent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894689/given-p-idempotent-show-that-i-p-is-idempotent)

PandaMan idea is that by proving $(I−P)^2 = (I-P)$ we prove that $(I-P)$ which implies that also $(I−P)^2$

My question is, how do we know/prove that $(I−P)^2$ is idempotent?

Thanks in advance!
/Luke

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SX! What are $I$ and $P$? Matrices?

Comment: Oh yes, I thought PandaMan's post mentioned it, sorry about that.

Comment: An idempotent is an element $e$ such that $e^2=e$. In the question that is linked, it is shown that for $e=(I-P)$ we have $e^2=e$. Therefore, $e=I-P$ is an idempotent. It is unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Let me rephrase. Given the matrix P is an idempotent, show that $(I - P)^2$ is an idempotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(I-P)^2 = I - 2P + P^2 = (I - P) + (P^2-P) = I-P$$

because $P^2-P = 0$ when $P$ is idempotent.

Comment: I already understand that $(I−P)^2 = (I-P)$. 
Let me rephrase my question. Given the matrix P is an idempotent, show that $(I−P)^2$ is an idempotent.

Comment: The definition of "$I-P$ is idempotent" is that $(I-P)^2=I-P$. If you understand that, then you understand why $I-P$ is idempotent...

Comment: Sometimes I underestimate my own stupidity... Thank you for your help.